# Any tool for visualizing multidimensional arrays?

Tags: multidimensional-array

Is there any software to visualize/edit/engineer multidimensinal arrays? Currently im using simple spreadsheet tools like MO:Excel or LO:Calc and doing it like this.
This is an example of 4D array. And it becomes harder and harder with adding new dimensions.

[image: "example of 4D array"]

Comment: You wouldn't consider using JSON? This is awful

Comment: @FirebladeDan JSON obj description doesnt looks like a visualization. Even http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ doesnt looks like a visualization...

Comment: @FirebladeDan oops, forgot to say that there is no associative array support in JSON format and its critical factor for me.

Comment: So JSON is just a way to store objects. It doesn't answer your visualization question but it would make it much easier to save things in a heirarchy vs an endless array location. That runtime fetch would be terrible

Comment: @FirebladeDan JSON is not a panacea. It cant be used everywhere and everytime. So that is why im asking about a tool to visualize multidim. arrays.